# Scala: sort list by sum of duration

Tags: scala, sorting, functional-programming

I have the following classes:

```
Task(id: String, time: Duration)

Product(id: String, tasks: List[Task])
```

Then, I have a list `list: List[Product]` with the following elements:

```
("P1", List(Task("T1", 15 minute), Task("T2", 10 minute)))

("P2", List(Task("T3", 10 minute)))

("P3", List(Task("T1", 15 minute)))
```

Now I want to order the list by the sum of the times that each product requires to be produced. In this case I wanted the output to be like so:

```
("P2", List(Task("T3", 10 minute))) // 10 min total

("P3", List(Task("T1", 15 minute))) // 15 min total

("P1", List(Task("T1", 15 minute), Task("T2", 10 minute))) // 25 min total
```

I thought about doing something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
list.sortBy(p => p.tasks.map(t => t.time))
```

Do you guys know how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to sort the list:

```
list.sortBy(
  p => p.tasks.map( t => t.time.toMillis ).sum
)
res1: List[Product] = List(
  Product(P2,List(Task(T3,10 minutes))),
  Product(P3,List(Task(T1,15 minutes))),
  Product(P1,List(Task(T1,15 minutes), Task(T2,10 minutes)))
)
```

To verify the sorted list:

```
list.map(
  p => ( p.id, p.tasks.map( t => t.time.toMinutes ).sum )
)
res2: List[(String, Long)] = List((P1,25), (P2,10), (P3,15)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are very close (you are not summing the durations in the inner list):

```
list.sortBy(p => p.tasks.foldLeft(Duration.ZERO)(_ plus _.time))
```

Note that it might make more sense to write a separate function here:

```
def totalTime(tasks: Seq[Task]): Duration 
  = tasks.foldLeft(Duration.ZERO)(_ plus _.time)
```

Because then you can write:

```
list.sortBy(p => totalTime(p.tasks))
```

---

**NOTES:**

You could also use a `reduce`, although you should do so safely (i.e. not assume your lists are non-empty)

```
def totalTime(tasks: Seq[Task]) 
  = tasks.map(_.time).reduceLeftOption(_ plus _).getOrElse(Duration.ZERO)
```

**More advanced**

If you are certain that your inner lists cannot be empty, you should use a datatype which enforces this, such as **scalaz**'s `NonEmptyList`. You could then use:

```
def totalTime(tasks: NonEmptyList[Task])
  = tasks.map(_.time).foldl1(_ plus _)
```

In fact, you could take advantage of the built-in *map-reduce* in scalaz (`foldMap`), although this would require declaring a `Semigroup[Duration]`:

```
implicit val DurationSemigroup: Semigroup[Duration]
  = Semigroup.instance(_ plus _)

def totalTime(tasks: NonEmptyList[Task]) = tasks.foldMap1(_.time))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort by time converting the time into nanos

```
scala> list.sortBy(p => p.tasks.map(_.time.toNanos).sum)
result: List[Product] = List(Product(P1,List(Task(T1,15 minutes), Task(T2,10 minutes))))
```